# Find the distance in Km with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, location

I want to calculate the distance from my location to another.
I found this line of code:

```
let distanceInMeters = location1.distanceFromLocation(location2)
```

But my problem is that I don't know how to take it from latitude and longitude.

Comment: So, you have lat and long? you just don't have location?

Comment: @PavelGatilov yes I dont know what format it should be.

Comment: But do you have latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you just need to create 2 CLLocation objects from your lat and long and then just call the line of code that you found.

```
let location1 = CLLocation(latitude: 20.0, longitude: 20.0)
let location2 = CLLocation(latitude: 30.0, longitude: 30.0)

let distanceInMeters = location1.distanceFromLocation(location2)
```

Also, this will return you distance in meters, not in km.

Comment: I test it with your numbers. I get this 1497148.92413003 when I print it.. Is it right?

Comment: @mikevorisis
Sure, it means that distance is almost 1500 km between 20N 20E and 30N 30E, which seems reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
var userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as! CLLocation
let long = userLocation.coordinate.longitude;
let lat = userLocation.coordinate.latitude;
// use it for your code     
}
```

You can try this function, I use it in my code

Comment: why do you need location manager if you already have latitude and longitude?